# a div above another?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, dom

i have some php files with html code in it and from my php file i have:

```
 require "popup.html";
 require "main.html";
```

then i use css to hide the div in popup.html.

when i click a link coupled to jquery to display the popup it will be above all divs in main.html except the ones that i have rendered in with ajax.

how can i make the popup div above all these ajaxed stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[z-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index)